# Should I ground the housing of an ungrounded well pump motor?

Tags: ground

I have a 25 year old deep water well pump with no ground. Two wires run 240v to the motor. Should I ground the body then run that to a ground?

Comment: 25 years ago grounds were normal and standard, and had been for 30+ years, so this is just a hack installation. Either that, or it's using metallic conduit for grounding. [Edit] in a picture.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you looked up the installation instructions for your brand/model? What do they say? Grounding is generally expected, but some items are double insulated and don't require it. (Your well motor is probably _not_ one of those double-insulated items, but it never hurts to double-check.)